Is it possible to define a macro that checks if a value falls within value range for any given sequential enum?
Given an enum which is assigned sequentially (i.e. the first value is 0 and the last value is the number of enumerations - 1), we can check if a value is a valid enum value like so:
enum e {FOO, BAR, BAZ};
int x = whatever;
if (x < 0 || x > 2)
    /* x is not an explicitly defined member of the enum */

Is it possible to define a macro which does this check that works for all sequential enums?

As an aside, "is a valid enum value" is not the same as "is within range of the members". For example, BAR | BAZ is a valid value, but larger than BAZ.


Is it possible to define a macro which does this check that works for all sequential enums?

No. C languge does not have reflection.
Typically you would:
enum e {FOO, BAR, BAZ, E_MAX};
if (0 <= x && x < E_MAX)


enum xyz { FOO, BAR, BAZ, ..., xyz_n}; is a good and common C idiom.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I see, it looks like a good idea. But now I get a bunch of warnings about unhandled cases in switch statements, so it looks like it not possible to use this idiom and have useful compiler diagnostics while eliminating those false positives.

@You'reNotARobot "get a bunch of warnings about unhandled cases in switch statements" --> Hmmm, do you have a default:?  It would be interesting to see sample code and the compiler settings that caused this in another post.

@chux-ReinstateMonica good point, I don't a default case for those functions. Actually the reason for me asking was related to this, I have some functions where given an invalid enum is a caller error and therefore I don't even want to spend time handling the default case, the program should immediately exit. So I wanted a macro like above so I could do assert(is_valid_enum_value(v)) at the start and then no need to handle the default case value (and the bonus is that in release builds I can disable the asset too).

You could #define E_MAX BAZ and #define IS_E(is_e) (0 < is_e && is_e <= E_MAX)), that would let the switch enum checks continue to work (I like switch checks). Or #define E_MAX (BAZ+1) if you prefer, though I'd call it E_LIM because it's not the maximum value enum e can have.

@JohnBayko nice idea.

I wanted to know how much I could torture C to make this work. I came up with this:
#define EE_VALUES { E1, E2, E3 }
enum ee_enum EE_VALUES;
#define IS_EE_ENUM(e) ((0 < e) && (e <= (sizeof((enum ee_enum[]) EE_VALUES)/sizeof(int))))

This takes the size of a hypothetical array of all enum values as the limit of an enum value. The standard array size macro is:
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])

But enums are represented as ints, so there's no need to repeat the array.
I don't know if this has a practical use, but there you have it.

Nope.  An enum type is known to the compiler.  The C preprocesor knows nothing about enums.
